# in admin panel when i click on checkbox user panel show the value of checkbox. how can i do it using mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, checkbox

Here only one can be click.  in admin panel when i click on buy checkbox it will display the value of checkbox in user panel. and when i click on sell checkbox it will display the value of checkbox in user panel.i want to show product name , buy value , sell value and date in user panel. how can i do it using mysql and php.

my database name is mydb. table name product and its column name are id, product , buy , sell , date .

here is Admin panel

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
          // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
          var $box = $(this);
          if ($box.is(":checked")) {
            // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
            // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
            var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
            // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
            // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
            $(group).prop("checked", false);
            $box.prop("checked", true);
          } else {
            $box.prop("checked", false);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    
      <table >
       <form action ="" method ="post">
      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Product Nane</th>
               <th>Buy</th>
               <th>Sell</th>
               <th>Date</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
              <tr>
       <td>abc</td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil[1][]"  value="buy"></td>
                 <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil[1][]"  value="sell"></td>
                    <td> <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")?> </td>
                </tr>
            
              <tr>
       <td>usd</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil[2][]" value="buy"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil[2][]"  value="sell"></td>
                    <td><?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")?> </td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>bfg</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil[3][]"  value="buy"></td>                 
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil[3][]"  value="sell" ></td>
               <td><?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")?> </td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
          <td></td>
                 <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
             </tr>
     </form>
    </table>
```

here is user panel

```
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
}

td {
    border: 5px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 13px;
}

</style>
<table >
        <tr>
            <th>Product Nane</th>
            <th>Buy</th>
            <th>Sell</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>

    <!-- value retrieve from database -->

        <tr>
            <td> </td> 
            <td>  </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

how to display product , buy ,sell, date value using mysql and php

Comment: Your JS code currently doing almost nothing. You will need to pass the value, to your DB, using a server side script.

Comment: here JS code is only for select one checkbox . like buy or sell .only one u can select . when u run code snippet  and click checkbox u can understand